# How to extend a C++ class by adding a new attribute with swig (Python)?

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have a C++ class that I need to extend by adding a new private attribute. I also need this to not be tied to a specific class so I'm using *define*. I've tried to do it the same way I add new methods, but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
%define add_new_attribute(cls)
  %extend MyClass {
         int new_attribute;
  };
%enddef
```

I don't really care if the new attribute is private or public, even though I'd prefer it be private. The documentation also doesn't say anything about this. Is there another way to do it?

EDIT:

There seems to be no problem with instantiating a new instance attribute from a method however. For example this is possible (which creates a sort of iterator that keeps it's state on the instance):

```
%pythoncode %{
    def mymethod(self):
        self.i = self.__dict__.get('i',0)
        self.i += 1
        print self.i
  %}
```

However I would really need this code to be in C++, because I need to dereference a pointer :).

Comment: I don't think that can work - it needs extra storage to be allocated for it in parts of your code which SWIG can't touch

Comment: Why do you need it to be in C++ unless it is some C++ data structure? SWIG will insert it in the wrapper file, one layer outside the original C++ class.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you are using %define. Just appending this to your swig interface file should work (I have not tested it for member variables, but I have used this for member function definitions):

```
 %extend MyClass {
         int new_attribute;
  }
```

Note that the last semicolon was redundant.

Comment: I said why I'm using define in the original post. Also I said that I tried this exact syntax and while it does work for methods, it does not work for attributes.